# variable object name in new object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code:

```
function newObject(arg){
  var objctToPush = {arg:["foo1","foo2"]};
  var obj = Object.assign(dataList,objectToPush);
  console.log(obj);
```

How can I set the objectname to the same as "arg"?

The output from log is:

```
Object { 0: Array(2), Names: Array(2), arg:Array(2)}
```

In this case "arg" should have the name 1

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Comment: As Teemu referred to, use square brackets: `var objectToPush = {[arg]:["foo1","foo2"]};`

Comment: Thanks that worked :-)

Comment: @AdrianGörisch Notice, that the computed property names are not supported in IEs, just in case you need to support these ancient browsers.

Comment: i use electron and nodeJS :-) but thanks for the info